# How to remove accent color from Start menu tiles only

Tags: windows, windows-10

I'm Windows 10 user (newest updates as of 2015.12.23).
I would love to change my accent color to some bright color like yellow.

But this also changes background of tiles in Start menu. And that looks ugly and unreadable.

Is there any way to disable accent color for Start menu tiles?

Dark accent color:

[image: Dark accent color]

Bright accent color:

[image: Bright accent color]

Comment: use a different start menu tool. The new one sucks

Comment: @magicandre1981 What do you mean by "Start menu tool"?

Comment: StartIsBack++, ClassicShell, Start10. The new buildin one sucks and nearly no customization options

Comment: @magicandre1981 I'll take a look. Thank you and have a nice new year.

Answer (score 0):

1. Set the color you want the Start Menu tiles to be in the *Settings* → *Personalization* → *Color*.
2. Open `regedit`.
3. To change the active window border color...

   1. Navigate to `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\DWM`.
   2. Set the value of `AccentColorMenu` to `ff00b9ff` (this is the yellow color from your screenshot). The value is ABGR Hex (Alpha, Blue, Green, Red).
4. To change the active window title bar color...

   1. Navigate to `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\DWM`.
   2. Set the value of `AccentColor` to `ff00b9ff`.
   3. Set the value of `ColorPrevalence` to `1` (`0` will make the active window title bar white).

Changes should take effect as soon as you change focus to another window.

Obviously, I can't show you my Start Menu and an Active Window in one screenshot, so I just took a few and made a GIF.

[image: Different accent color for Start Menu and Windows]

**Notes**

1. I have no idea yet where the Start Menu and Taskbar are pulling the accent color from.
2. I'm running on Windows 10 version 1803. I have not tried this with earlier versions.
3. One of my tiles is red because I was messing with [`.VisualElementsManifest.xml` method to change the color of individual tiles](https://www.askvg.com/tip-customize-start-screen-tiles-background-color-text-color-and-logo-in-windows-8-1/).