# How to remove colored window outline in Windows 10?

Tags: windows-10, colors

Notice the blue border around the settings window:

[image]

I have that blue border because I changed my accent color to blue. I want my accent color to be blue so the start menu buttons are blue, but I don't want that window border (regardless of color) at all. How can I remove it? i.e. through the registry

Answer (score 23):

If coming here due to a blue box appearing around **anything** that you select (i.e. mouse click or tab to):

This is due to **Narrator** running.

To turn it off hold down the <kbd>Caps Lock</kbd> key and press the <kbd>Esc</kbd> key.

You can also [permanently disable Narrator](https://superuser.com/questions/473410/disable-narrator-shortcut-key-in-windows-8).

Answer (score 6):

From [a Reddit thread](https://www.reddit.com/r/Windows10/comments/3blaf8/that_1pixel_window_border/):

> 1. Hit WIN+R , type Control Color and press enter.
> 2. Lower "Color Intensity" to 0 (All the way to the left. This does not affect the accent color intensity whatsoever)
> 3. Feel at peace with your desktop again

Comment: That didn't remove it for me: http://i.imgur.com/lnUYUgs.png

Comment: Yeah, on that reddit post someone mentioned it only looked solved because of the environment the screenshot was taken in: https://www.reddit.com/r/Windows10/comments/3blaf8/that_1pixel_window_border/cx4dk1r

Comment: I should have clarified - it doesn't remove it completely, just reduces the impact.

Comment: After pressing "Save changes" it keeps changes to the color, but not changes to the color intensity for me.

Answer (score 1):

1. Open `regedit` and navigate to `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\Accent`
2. Set the value `AccentColorMenu` to `0`.

Take a look at my answer to the question [How to remove accent color from Start menu tiles only](https://superuser.com/a/1395550/109949) for more info.

Answer (score 0):

Try to Right click on **Desktop** > **Personalize** > **Themes**.
Please change your current theme and then this problem will be fixed. Your current theme is simply corrupt.

Comment: This was the correct answer for me. Theme > windows. It wasn't corrupt just placing the outline after an update

Answer (score 0):

Right click on desktop=>click on Personalize=>click on high contrast settings=> turn off.

It work for me

Answer (score -1):

The ways I have looked at is the Local Group Policy editor (if you have pro). Or to make it easier.

Right Click on the screen.
Select Personalize.
Select Colors.
Unselect Automatically select from background.
I turned on all the sliders and selected dark mode.
Then I selected the dark grey. The color is still there but much less in your face.

Comment: OP said they wanted to keep the blue color, your solution changes this to grey. As you can see in the screenshot, OP also already enabled dark mode.